# Error installing Accelerator for HL7. Installation cannot be performed because user account is not a member of Biztalk Server Administrators group

Tags: sql-server-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Please consider the following error when trying to run the HL7 Accelerator Setup.exe executable.

[image: Install Error]

I'm installing on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.

BizTalk 2013 is already installed and configured successfully using Global domain groups for BizTalk Server Administrators (and all other groups for that matter). I am a part of all groups.

SQL Server 2012 SP3 was installed prior to BizTalk

When I go to run the HL7 Accelerator MSI, I get the error pictured above, which states:

> Error: Installation cannot be performed because the BizTalk server has not been configured or user account is not a member of the BizTalk Server Administrators group

Like I said, BizTalk is configured, the groups are Global and I'm a member, I'm also a local admin on the machine.

I've also tried this altered MSI [from this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mandi/2014/06/22/the-handle-is-invalid-error-installing-hl7/) to no avail, I get the same error.

I'm at a loss. I can't find anything anywhere explicitly saying that any of these versions are incompatible, and I know SQL Server 2012 SP1 is compatible based on other installations we have running.

Could it be something with Windows Server 2012 R2? I don't know how I'd get this far and not be allowed to install the accelerator of all things.

Comment: Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx  Looks like you are OK there with the software (Windows & SQL).  However this question is a bit of topic for StackOverflow, you may want to post this on https://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I did end up posting it there right after this. Just today I added more details:  http://serverfault.com/questions/782812/error-installing-accelerator-for-hl7-installation-cannot-be-performed-because-u I ended up wiping the VM and installing SQL Server 2008 R2...but the DBA installed SP4 -- I can't imagine that is the problem (requirements state SP1)